# Condicional no funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, condiciones, if

Al inicio de mi pagina, hay una canción que se reproduce automáticamente. Cuando termina, esta debiese pasar a la siguiente canción, sin embargo no entiendo por qué no lo esta haciendo, si en mi condicional le coloco que, al terminar la canción, se inicie la siguiente. 
La alerta dentro de mi funcion no aparece.

El código es el siguiente:

```js
currentTrack = 0

beats = ['eminem.mp3', 'icecube.mp3', 'lilwayne.mp3', 'nas.mp3', 'still.mp3', 'today.mp3']

beat = document.getElementById('beat')

if(beat.ended == true){

function reproducir(){



alert("estoy dentro de la funcion")
 


nextTrack = beats[currectTrack++]
beat.setAttribute('src', nextTrack)
beat.play

})

}
```

```html
<audio src="../estudio/beats/eminem.mp3" autoplay controls id="beat"></audio>
<button onclick="reproducir()">iniciar</button>
<button onclick="detener()">detener</button>
<div id="seccion"></div>
```

¿Por qué ocurre eso?¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: has intentado colocar un alert() dentro y fuera de la condicional, para ver si la funcion esta siendo llamada correctamente y ademas si esta correcto el javascript?

Comment: acabo de colocarlo dentro y fuera de la condicional, cuando la cancion que inicia al inicio de la pagina termina no se muestra la alerta, pero si presiono mi boton reproducir me muestra primero la alerta fuera de la condicion. sin embargo cuando termina la cancion y presiono el boton reproducir si se muestran las dos alertas

Answer (score 0):

Como observación, en esa condicional siempre se está asignando la última pista al reproductor. Si ese no es el efecto deseado, corrígelo.

El problema es que dicha condicional **se está ejecutando una sola vez**, en cuando `reproducir` es ejecutado, es decir, cuando se pulse el botón *Iniciar*. Si lo que quieres es que pase automáticamente a la siguiente canción debes usar el evento `end`:

```
let currentTrack = 0; // lleva un control de la pista actual

beat.addEventListener('end', e => {
  const nextTrack = beats[currentTrack++];
  beat.setAttribute('src', nextTrack);
  beat.play();
}
```

Si, por otro lado, quieres que se al pausar y acto seguido, iniciar de nuevo, cambie de pista, el evento que necesitas es `pause`:

```
beat.addEventListener('pause', e => {
  const nextTrack = beats[++currentTrack];
  beat.setAttribute('src', nextTrack);
  beat.play();
};
```

De ésta manera al pausar el reproductor, el índice de la canción aumenta y, cuando vuelvas a iniciar la cación obtiene una nueva pista y la ejecuta.

Comment: acabo de editar mi codigo, ahora pongo la condicional antes de mi funcion ante esto no entiendo porque razon no funciona, si le digo que cuando se haya terminado la cancion corriente, entre a la funcion y muestre la alerta, alemenos deberia mostrar la alerta

Comment: 1. `play` es un método, no una propiedad, por ende, debe ejecutarse. 2. Tienes un error de sintaxis (`}) <-- este paréntesis`). Elimina errores de sintaxis antes de publicarlo como un problema.